# Bootstrap 3 Glyphicon not aligned in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a simple dropdown menu using Bootstrap 3 to sort my list of users as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="sortUsers" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Sort by
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="sortUsers">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">First Name<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Last Name</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Nickname</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, the glyphicon is not aligned on the same line. How can I make it be on the same line as "First Name"?

[image: User sort dropdown menu]

Comment: Check your code again.
I test your code. It work. [Look here](http://jsbin.com/bevagi/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Works for me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for your investigations. Since it appears that the JavaScript and HTML are not the problems, I decided to check my css file and found that I was overriding the default dropdown class specs. I have since adjusted it, and now it works as expected. Thanks again for all those who helped, I will upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

What version of bootstrap are you using?
New version 3.3.1 works just fine, here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9050/

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="sortUsers" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Sort by
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="sortUsers">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">First Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Last Name</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Nickname</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```